# Restricted mean survival time with stpm2 in Stata: No confidence intervals after margins command

Tags: survival, stata

I want to calculate restricted mean survival time using stpm2 and margins in Stata.

```
webuse brcancer, clear
stset rectime, failure(censrec = 1)

stpm2 i.x4, df(3) scale(haz)

margins i.x4, predict(rmst tmax(3000))
```

No confidence intervals are shown for covariate level x4==1.

```
margins i.x4, predict(rmst tmax(3000))
```

Why? Obviously, the confidence interval calculation depends on tmax(.), since when e.g. tmax(1000), then confidence intervals are calculated.

```
margins i.x4, predict(rmst tmax(1000))
```